# Error when building Process Control Daemon (PCD)

Tags: c++, process, kernel, arm

I'm getting this compilation error when building [PCD](http://www.rt-embedded.com/blog/pcd-process-control-daemon/). There seems to be an undeclared variable (PCD latest version, 1.1.6)

> /pcd-1.1.6/pcd/src/process.c:506:34: error: ‘PRIO_PROCESS’ undeclared
>   (first use in this function)
>                        setpriority( PRIO_PROCESS, 0, rule->sched.niceSched );

is this a known issue?

Answer (score 2):

I added

```
#include <sys/resource.h>
```

to process.c and it works now.